# Unable to stop the Bash command running when terminal is opened

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, bash

Whenever I open terminal in Ubuntu 14.04, I get the following command as soon as terminal opens:

bash: “source/usr/local/share/chruby/chruby.sh”: No such file or directoy

How can I stop the bash file from being executed upon opening the terminal?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete that line from `.bash-profile`.

If you waht to stop reading whole `.bash-profile` file, edit `.profile` file.

Comment: Thanks, How do I get into the .bash-profile? sorry I am new to Linux

Comment: Show hidden files in file manager: Ctrl+H. I thought you knew, since it's in your tag. Actualy it can also be .bashrc.